# How to read/get cookies at the Client side using Java Springs?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, cookies

Is it possible get a cookie whose name is known to me but was set by another app?
I tried  this code -

```
Cookie[] cookie = request.getCookies();
```

I am getting null in `cookie` but there are a lot of cookies I can see in my browser settings-> All Cookiesand Site Data.

Is it possible to get a cookie that we don't set? I can put the Springs App in the same tomcat as that of the app that set the cookie.

PS: I don't know Springs but need to do this if possible, I might have sounded bad while asking the question.

Comment: Imagine how convenient it would be if this was possible. Everyone could steal your login credentials for Google, Facebook, PayPal...

Comment: So two `.war` kept in same server can not get each other's cookies?

Comment: Yes, they can, provided the cookies have the right path. Note: the project is named Spring, not Springs.

Comment: @JBNizet thank you, I am trying wat u suggested